# Screen turns black but doesn't lock when I press Ctrl+Alt+L

Tags: lock-screen

I am unable to lock my desktop in Ubuntu 11.10 with

Ctrl + Alt + L

If I press the above key sequence the screen turns black and the little lock icon appears at the top right of my screen.

However, if I press a key or move my mouse, the black screen disappears and my desktop appears again.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice - I've merge your two questions.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a password in "user accounts" then Ctrl + Alt + L will lock with a password. If you don't want to have to type in a password for log on then simply enable automatic log on. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Hi Ross. I do have a password for user accounts, but it is not working.

Comment: Have your tried removing it and setting it again?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have the Lock option set in *System Settings - Screen*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's working to me? The lock screen doesn't ask for password when resuming by default, you have to enable that functionality.

As for a lock icon, I don't recall ever seeing one. (Then again, I don't lock my computer)

Comment: Brian, could you please tell me how to enable password? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

It maybe a god function in windows OS,and you get used to it,probably.but it cannot keep you private safe,after all lock screen with passwords just do it.

Comment: Windows? You're answering a question in AskUbuntu. EDIT: I'm four years too late.