# How to add screen-lock password to Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screen turns black but doesn't lock when I press Ctrl+Alt+L](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111517/screen-turns-black-but-doesnt-lock-when-i-press-ctrlaltl)

Could someone please tell me how I can add a password to Ubuntu 11.10 screen lock? For example, after I press Ctrl + Alt + L and lock, if I were to move my mouse or press a key there would be a prompt for my account password.

Thanks.